# Data install script not adding data

Tags: model, magento-1, setup-script, install-script

I'm trying to add an entry to a custom table with a data-install script but it isn't setting the data when I call `->save()` method it just add an empty value in the field.

I have updated the config.xml file and the script is running but not adding the entries.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$values = array(
        'id' => 1,
        'customer_id' => rand(),
        'prima_id' => rand(),
        'guest' => 0,
        'email' => 'Youghtley1987@armyspy.com',
);
$data = Mage::getModel('modulename/tablename');
foreach($values as $key => $value) {

   $data->setData($value)->save();

}
```

For some reason the $value is not being set and saved and I can't see why?

Comment: why you use $data = Mage::getModel('mobulename/tablename')->getCollection();?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not work because you use `setData()` in the wrong way. With only one parameter it replaces the whole data array, But `1`, `rand()`, `0` and `'Youghtley1987@armyspy.com'` are all not arrays.

If you used `setData($key, $value)`, you would set each attribute individually, which works, but you save the whole row after setting each individual attribute. You should set them all at once, then save once.

### The corrected code:

```
$values = array(
        'id' => 1,
        'customer_id' => rand(),
        'prima_id' => rand(),
        'guest' => 0,
        'email' => 'Youghtley1987@armyspy.com',
);
$data = Mage::getModel('modulename/tablename');

$data->setData($values)->save();
```

Note that if `id` is the "id column" of this model and not configured as `_isPkAutoIncrement=false`, this code will try to update an existing entry with id "1". Leave it out if you want to add a new entry with auto increment id.

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

Remove **save()** function from loop and also `set table columns  value by key` using `setData('fieldKey','fieldValue')`

```
$data = Mage::getModel('mobulename/tablename');
foreach($values as $key => $value) {

$data->setData($key,$value)

}

$data->save();
```

Easy solution:

Instead of update  `each columns value one  by one using loop`.use **addData()** for update data quickly

```
$values = array(
        'id' => 1,
        'customer_id' => rand(),
        'prima_id' => rand(),
        'guest' => 0,
        'email' => 'Youghtley1987@armyspy.com',
);
$data = Mage::getModel('modulename/tablename');
$data->addData($value)->save();
```

**NOte:** If  **id**  is `primary key for this table` then it good id set primary key like this;

Comment: Sorry, that was left in by mistake, I've updated the code now which still doesn't add the values

Comment: Sorry, that was left in by mistake, I've updated the code now which still doesn't add the values. Not fully sure what you mean by load the object as there is no data in the table I want to add one entry when the data script runs.